# cURL post fields is encoded with special char

Tags: c++, curl

I'm using cURL in Visual C++ curl pointer shared to an function.
setData function is encoded sent to server, but without function no there encoded problem. Why such problem there?

Source:

```
static size_t WriteCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
    ((std::string*)userp)->append((char*)contents, size * nmemb);

    return size * nmemb;
}

void setData(CURL *curl) // bad working (encoded sent fields...)
{
    string fields = "{\"daa\": \"a\"}";

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, fields.c_str());
}

void setUrl(CURL* curl) // good working
{
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com");
}

int main()
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
    string readBuffer;

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    struct curl_slist *list = NULL;

    list = curl_slist_append(list, "Content-Type: application/json");

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, list);

    setUrl(curl);
    setData(curl);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    cout << readBuffer;

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Never used this as a library.  But just checking the man page.  Have you tried `CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS ` instead of `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` ?

Comment: And more from the manual... you might want a `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE` setter in there too.  But maybe not, since it is a zero terminated c_str

Comment: @infixed your solution now tried working. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is a matter of storage ownership.

If you use `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`, you must make sure the data storage will stay persistent until you are done using it with curl.  Since in your program that string is a local variable, it presents a problem.  When the subroutine ends, ownership went away and something else can use that memory.

If you use the variation `CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS` you'll get around that, because curl will copy the data to storage it owns